# Too few parameters error when ordering results by Year, Month, Day

Tags: sorting, ms-access, coldfusion

I'm trying to group results by Year, Month, Day for output.

```
2019
  February
      Day
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and wonder if it is an MS Access issue. The following code produces a *too few parameters* error.

```
<cfquery name="nchklist" datasource="#fds#">
    SELECT year(chkdate) AS Year, month(chkdate) AS month, day(chkdate) AS day, vcheck
    FROM vchk
    where vid = '#vid#' and final = 1
    ORDER BY year, month, day
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="nchklist" group="year">

    <cfoutput group="month">
        #monthAsString(month)#

        <cfoutput group="day">
            <a href="create_report.cfm?vcheck=#vcheck#">View</a> :  DateFormat(chkdate, 'dddd - mmmm d, yyyy')#<br>
        </cfoutput>

    </cfoutput>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This typically indicates a missing or misspelled field or table name.

Comment: Just checked : all fields are correct.  Works if I do a Select * from vchk where vid = '#vid#' and final = 1 order by chkdate

Comment: Year, Month, Day are reserved words (they are functions as you should be aware since you are using them) and should not be used as names for anything. Using reserved words as names is known to cause issues in some situations. However, I just did a test of this in Access query object and it does work.

Comment: @June7 - Sorry, didn't see your comment before posting. That's almost certainly the problem. It may work in Access, but CF uses a JDBC driver to connect to MS Access databases. IIRC it may behave differently than a direct query in Access with regard to reserved words.

Comment: Too bad SO doesn't notify of new comments the way it does new answers...

Comment: On a side note: Is Access being used on a personal system or is this a Production system? Access isn't really suitable for Production use. If you need to interact with a database, you'd be much better off actually installing a real RDBMS. And you'd avoid a lot of the issues that come with using an Access db.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

It's been years since I've used Access, so my knowledge is kind of hazy, but I'm starting to remember it had limitations with the ORDER BY clause. Unlike a true DBMS, it wasn't smart enough to allow ordering by column *aliases*. I don't know if that's changed in recent versions, but ... like I mentioned earlier, you should try ordering by the original expressions - NOT the aliases:

```
ORDER BY year(chkdate), month(chkdate), day(chkdate)
```

As an aside, CF isn't a great sql debugging tool. It communicates with databases indirectly, usually via JDBC drivers. That process often returns far more generic error messages than you'd receive than from using standard database tools. Whenever you encounter a cryptic error like that, **best to run the sql query directly within the database**, hard coding parameters as needed. Doing that probably would've given you a less cryptic error message, or at least indicated the ORDER BY clause was the problem.

---

As [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677615/cold-fusion-ms-access-order-results-by-year-month-day#comment96144617_54677615), that error may indicate a misspelled column name. It can also occur when a reserved word is used as column name or alias. Notice your query uses functions named `Year`, `Month` and `Day`? Those are [reserved words in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-AE9D9ADA-3255-4B12-91A9-F855BDD9C5A2). That's probably the cause of the error. Try changing your column aliases to non-reserved words, for example `TheYear`, `TheMonth`, `TheDay`.

Assuming MS Access supports ordering by column aliases, try the query below:

```
 SELECT year(chkdate) AS TheYear
        , month(chkdate) AS TheMonth
        , day(chkdate) AS TheDay
        , vcheck
 FROM   vchk
 WHERE  vid = <cfqueryparam value="#vid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
 AND    final = 1
 ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth, TheDay
```

Note: Even with MS Access, queries should always use cfqueryparam on all input parameters.

Comment: Still getting error on where vid = <cfqueryparam value="#vid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> ( Too few parameters. Expected 4 ) and with   vid = '<cfqueryparam value="#vid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">' ( Invalid parameter binding(s) )

Comment: I don't know Access well, but "final" is a reserved word in some languages. I'd try changing or escaping that column name. Also, what happens if you run the SQL in directly in Access, using a hard coded value for "vid"?

Comment: Doesn't matter when removing final. Is there an easier way to group results in year, month?

Comment: That's the simplest way. 1. Did you also change the column aliases? 2. What happens when you run the SQL directly in Access (no CF involved)?

Comment: All the fields. columns are correct... I haven't run in Access no, I avoid that at risk of creating Macros etc... I let CF run things...

Comment: Executing a sql statement doesn't create macros. Running it directly in the database will help identify if the problem is the sql statement or the jdbc driver. If you can't do that, for some reason, you'll have to  take the long route. Break down the statement and run pieces of the sql, until it breaks. I.e. Run SELECT * FROM Table. Add back the WHERE clause, etc...